# Currently selected indicator's colour in flag summary and help pages, can be the same as the site's colour code

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Some of the Stack Exchange sites has it's own colour code. Like Meta Stack Exchange has `#17a7db`, ELU has `#AE3737`, Travel has `#277789` for the currently selected item's indicators in main page and the user activity page.

But in the flag summary section and help pages of those sites, the indicator has the colour of `#F48024` which is same as the Stack Overflow site's colour code.

So instead of applying the Stack Overflow's colour code to all the sites, shall we apply the site's specific colour code in flag summary and help pages too.

**Selected indicator in flag summary section of MSE, ELU and Travel:**

> [image: Meta Stack Exchange]
>
> [image: English Language & Usage]
>
> [image: Travel Stack Exchange]

**Selected indicator in help page:**

> [image: Meta Stack Exchange - help pages]

Comment: Seems the site theme is applied to the help center and flag summary pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Agreed. I've opened a [PR in our component library](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/248) to make this color configurable. After the next Stacks update, the Q&A code can then easily set this color to match the site theme's primary color.

I'll mark this question as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) once that has shipped.

Comment: Would it be possible to change the background of the sidebar element from yellow to white as it is [in the Stacks documentation](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/sidebar-widgets#second-level-navigation)?

Comment: @MEEisJohannGambolputty... Possible, sure -- this is just using one of the [color alternatives](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/sidebar-widgets#alternative-colors). I'll ping a designer on opinions here.

Comment: Something new about the bg change? I just saw that this was completed.