# Apply the site primary theme color in the edit profile page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, profile-page

In all the Stack Exchange per-site and per-site meta's Edit Profile page, the sub menu titles (PERSONAL INFORMATION, EMAIL SETTINGS, SITE SETTINGS, ...) and markdown editor toolbar hover color are set to orange, the same color of Stack Overflow's primary theme color.

Since each site has its own primary theme color, so instead of applying the Stack Overflow's color code to all the sites, can we apply the site's primary theme color code in Edit Profile pages too.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Edit profile]

<sub>There was a same kind of change was requested and corrected. [Related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323309/312043)</sub>

Comment: Workaround for the wrong colour of the icons in the editor window: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400946/2777074

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the new design change, the site's primary theme color is applied to the Edit profile page's tab titles.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: new design]